# Avoid 'SettingWithCopyWarning:' when setting values with loc and conditions (inside a function)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to set some values in one column (col_2) coming from another column (col_3) when values in col_1 fulfill a condition.
I'm doing that with the .loc operator as after all my research looking for alternatives it looks as the best practice.

`data.loc[data.col_1.isin(['A','B']),col_2]=data[col_3]`

Nevertheless this stills trigger the 'SettingWithCopyWarning:'.

Is there any other way to do this operation without raising that warning?

Comment: This is most likely because your `data` variable is a subset of another dataframe (e.g. you created `data` with some type of `data = some_df.loc[...]`. You can use `data = data.copy()` before you try to change the values in `data` to remedy this warning though.

Answer (score 0):

Following the advice of Cameron,the line of code was part of a function, where data was passed as argument.

Starting the function with `data = data.copy()` solves the issue